# Kotlin: Nested class unable to get access to outerclass variables

Tags: java, kotlin, class, junit, inner-classes

I'm new to Kotlin and have little experience with Java, so please bear with me. From what I've been able to research ([here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-classes-java/), for example), it appears that `mockFoo` should be accessible from the outer class, but IntelliJ is giving me an `Unresolved Reference` error.

```
@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)
class GetBazTest {
    @MockK
    private lateinit var mockFoo: FooClient

    @MockK
    private lateinit var mockBar: BarClient

    private lateinit var getBaz: GetBaz

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        getBaz = GetBaz(
            mockFoo,
            mockBar,
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun `it should do a thing`() {
        // some code to create expectedResult

        coEvery {
            mockFoo.getSomething(any())
        } answers {
            expectedResult
        }
    }


    @Nested
    @DisplayName("Tests for Xyz")
    class XyzTest {
        @Test
        fun `it should do a different thing`() {
            // some code to create expectedResult

            coEvery {
                mockFoo.getAThing(any()) // mockFoo gives Unresolved Reference error
            } answers {
                expectedResult
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It doesn't seem right that I would need to `setUp` `mockFoo` again in the inner class. How do I access the outer variables?

Comment: Java's regular nested classes correspond to Kotlin's `inner` classes, while Java's `static` nested classes correspond to Kotlin's regular nested classes. The difference between both kinds is that instances of Kotlin inner classes (or java regular nested classes) are tied to a specific instance of the containing class, while static nested classes are not. I hope this is clear :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply make XyzTest an `inner` class to grant him access to outer-class members

```kotlin
@Nested
@DisplayName("Tests for Xyz")
inner class XyzTest { ...
```